# SQLPLUS 32-bit Linux Pathing Issue

Tags: linux, bash, path, oracle-11g

I am running linux 32 bit and installed Oracle 11g in it. I am trying to start sqlplus from command line but get the command not found error.

I checked the environment variables and have

`ORACLE_HOME=/home/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1`

the sqlplus executable lies in

`/home/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/bin`

my .bash_profile looks like this:

`PATH=$PATH:/home/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/bin`

I also made sure I exported ORACLE_HOME after I set the path.

Weird thing is I did

`echo $PATH`

and did not see the ORACLE_HOME path returned. is .bash_profile the wrong file to edit? I didn't see any other profile files.

I have also tried setting Oracle_HOME as: `/home/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/bin/sqlplus` but still did got a command not found result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you actually using `bash`?

```
echo $0
```

should tell you this.  Also try `export`ing `$PATH` (`export PATH` after `PATH=…`).  To be sure that your `~/.bash_profile` is actually read in your shell, you could insert something like

```
echo "now sourcing ~/.bash_profile"
```

somewhere into it.

**Note:** `~/.bash_profile` is only read if bash is started as *login* shell.  If you're trying from within an `xterm` or so, it might not get read, since most terminal emulators are configured not to act as login shell.  In this case, edit `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: `echo $0` returned bash.  I am logging in remotely and am using xterm, so that might be it.  Weird thing is, I checked both PATH and ORACLE_HOME earlier today and it seems both variables were reset which makes me believe there is something else out there that resets it later, just not sure what that is.  Ultimately I was able to log in to SQLPLUS and thanks for the help.